# how to use string variable as table variable in scaler values function

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am trying to make a scaler values function in sql server.

This function will take a comma seperated string of Ids and will return comma seperated string of text values corresponding to the ids.

i am passing all parameters (like : @tablename, @idcolumnname, @valuecolumnname, @stringofids etc). and firstly try to get single text value as

select @valuecolumnname from @tablename where @idcolumnname= (a value from @stringofids )

but i am not able to select the text value from table corresponding to id taken from comma seperated string of ids. it gives following error

Must declare the table variable "@tablename". i am passing @tablename as string. what should i do.

Comment: If you pass @tablename as a string you should use dynamic sql query `sp_executesql()` [link](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: Unfortunately `sp_executesql` is not allowed inside scalar function.

Comment: yes. so no way to do this  ???